# What should follow the word crazy, About, or Over, or both?

Tags: prepositions

Is going crazy about something the same as going crazy over it?

I mean.

I was crazy about/over it.

What's the difference between going crazy about something, and going crazy over it?

Answer (score 2):

They're similar in usage when they mean "passionate".  Context and emphasis are very much needed to determine just how much it is "unreasonable" or "insane" vs. just "intense"... or even if it's "crazy good" or "crazy bad".

But "crazy about" is generally a clear statement of intensely liking something.   So `I'm crazy about this new StackExchange site` would mean you like the site a lot.  It doesn't usually mean that the interest level is actually "irrational" or "unjustified".

"crazy over" is more likely to be used with "going", and often does suggest something actually unreasonable is happening.  `People are going crazy over (some toy) this Christmas--parents are getting in fistfights at the store to be first in line to buy one.`

If the 'crazy' is emphasized, it might really mean crazy:

- `When the neighbors have parties on Fridays and play their loud music, he's *crazy* about it.  Starts yelling, beating on the walls, threatening to change into a werewolf and go eat them.`  (Generally that would include get, as in "he gets crazy about it")

> I was crazy about/over it.

Here specifically, you'd most likely see:

- `I was crazy about it.` (probably means: "I really liked it.")
- `I went crazy over it.` (probably means: "It really upset me.")

Again, there's a lot of leeway with this from context.